# how to tell if column is primary key using mysqli?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, primary-key

I am converting some of my code from the older mysql extension to the mysqli extension in PHP.  Previously, with the mysql extension, I had used some code like this to find the primary key in a table:

```
while ($i < mysql_num_fields($result)) {
    $meta = mysql_fetch_field($result, $i);
    if ($meta->primary_key == 1){ 
        $primary_key = $meta->name; 
    }
    $i++;
}
```

`$meta->primary_key == 1` was very convenient.

So far I have converted to code to using mysqli:

```
while ($i < $result->field_count) {
    $meta = $result->fetch_field;
    if ($meta->primary_key == 1){ 
        $primary_key = $meta->name; 
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Of course, from looking at the docs [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-field.php) we can see that `$meta->primary_key` doesn't exist in mysqli.  I see that there is a `$meta->flags`.  This is my best guess, although i am not sure of what value `flags` should be when I have a primary key.

Does anyone know how I tell which column is the primary key for a table using mysqli?

Thanks!

**EDIT**
Here is some working code:

```
//get primary key
$primary_key = '';
while ($meta = $result->fetch_field()) {
    if ($meta->flags & MYSQLI_PRI_KEY_FLAG) { 
        $primary_key = $meta->name; 
    }
}
```

Comment: run the "describe `table_name`" query?

Comment: Good point, that would require a separate transaction with the DB, which is doable.  I prefer to use the info already obtained in the result set.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You were very close, you will need the `flags` property.

The flag you are looking for is [`MYSQLI_PRI_KEY_FLAG`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.constants.php#constantmysqli-pri-key-flag), which means:

> Field is part of a primary index

You can test for this flag with something like:

```
if ($meta->flags & MYSQLI_PRI_KEY_FLAG) { 
  //it is a primary key!
}
```

You are using `&` here as a [Bitwise AND Operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php).